# Which of these is the preferred method for funneling Objective-C initializers?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

Given the following initializers

```
- (id)initWithParameterA:(A *)a
{
    return [self initWithParameterA:a parameterB:nil parameterC:nil];
}

- (id)initWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b
{
    return [self initWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:nil];
}

- (id)initWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b parameterC:(C *)c
{
    // Actual initialization logic
}
```

which of the following two groups of convenience initializers is preferable? (Assuming ARC.)

**Group A**

```
+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a
{
    return [self objectWithParameterA:a parameterB:nil parameterC:nil];
}

+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b
{
    return [self objectWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:nil];
}

+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b parameterC:(C *)c
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:c];
}
```

**Group B**

```
+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithParameterA:a parameterB:nil parameterC:nil];
}

+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:nil];
}

+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b parameterC:(C *)c
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:c];
}
```

I understand the trivial implication that **Group A** results in an additional method call to get to the actual initialization logic, but is there anything more profound about either design?

Comment: Do whichever is easiest to maintain, unless the profiler tells you it's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit too much opinion based - so everyone you ask is likely to be different.

Which group you use is a matter of style although I would go with the DRY'er code which is group A. I would probably even do

```
+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a
{
    return [self objectWithParameterA:a parameterB:nil];
}

+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b
{
    return [self objectWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:nil];
}

+ (id)objectWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b parameterC:(C *)c
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:c];
}
```

It adds another method call but I'm not repeating `return [self objectWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:nil];` this line twice. I would only worry about the performance hit of method calls if profiling proved this was an issue.

I would then probably give the `init` methods the same treatment

```
- (id)initWithParameterA:(A *)a
{
    return [self initWithParameterA:a parameterB:nil];
}

- (id)initWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b
{
    return [self initWithParameterA:a parameterB:b parameterC:nil];
}

- (id)initWithParameterA:(A *)a parameterB:(B *)b parameterC:(C *)c
{
    // Actual initialization logic
}
```

Comment: I actually had this style initially, so I think you may be right that it's just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Either with one important caveat: the convention is that `object...` should return a non-retained object, while `new...` should return a retained one. So pre-ARC your `object...` methods would have included an `autorelease`. Now post-ARC you can't do this, so the `new...` pattern so long neglected has been breathed new life.

Clarification after @Rob's comment: ARC will produce the correct code for `object...` and `new...` - in the former it will insert the autorelease you used to have to do manually (it doesn't need to change the code for the latter as alloc + init gives you a retained object). Given this I think the `new...` form, long neglected, is a good fit for ARC code - not needing to do an autorelease is better than doing one.

Comment: In ARC, the autorelease is done automatically if the method name doesn't fit the new/alloc/copy pattern.

Comment: @Rob: Correct, I wasn't clear was I. I'll clarify in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in all-ARC code as the compiler will strip out redundant retain / release / autorelease calls...

Comment: @hypercrypt: We're talking about code in *different* files here - the `object...`/`new...` and the code calling those methods. While it is *possible* that the ARC compiler does whole-application optimisation, I doubt it does as most compilers do not. Furthermore if the class is compiled into a library to be used by other apps then whole-application optimisation is probably out. For these and other reasons don't expect that autorelease to disappear, just be happy if it does :-)